# C# IEnumerable<T>, how to assign values to the members / properties of T

Tags: c#, class, generics, ienumerable

Below is my structure in c#

```
  public class Search
    {
        public IEnumerable<Cars> Cardetail { get; set; }
    }

 public class Cars
    {
        public string Id{ get; set; }
        public string StatusCode { get; set; }
        
    }
```

Now I want to assign data to the Cars.Id and Cars.Status code for unit testig

How to assign it since it is part of the IEnumerbale

I tried like

```
new Search()
{
 Cardetail = <IEnumerable> Cars{ Id ="1"} // but throws error 
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `<IEnumerable> Cars{ Id ="1"}` looks nothing like valid C#. It's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Create an object that implements `IEnumerable<Cars>` and assign that e.g. `List<Cars>`.

Comment: `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, `T[]` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, numerous other collection types implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: `new List<Cars>() { new Car { Id = 1, StatusCode = "status"});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var search = new Search
{
    Cardetail = new Car[]
    {
        new Car
        {
            Id = "UniqueId",
            StatusCode = "MyFancyStatusCode"
        }
    }
}
```

This code should probably do what you're trying to achieve.

When creating an instance of a class with the `new` keyword, you can use [Object and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

Instead of writing this

```
var search = new Search();
search.Cardetail = ...
```

we assign `Cardetail` in the curly braces.

For `Cardetail` we have to decide for an implementation to use, since `Cardetail` is of type `IEnumerable<T>` which is an [Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) and we cannot create instances of interfaces. We need a type which *implements* this specific interface like `Array` or `List<T>` (there are many more).

Comment: Can you run me through how this is materially different to Jamiec's answer?

Comment: Jamiec's answer and mine are pretty much the same. He additionally provided you and example on how to initialize Cardetails using a List<T>. My code is just formatted to the max using linebreaks on curly braces.

Comment: If you could avoid posting answers that differ only from some other answer due to some minor thing like whitespace or variable naming, the community in general would appreciate it. If you feel there's a considerable or interesting/vital extra detail that an existing answer has missed off, then feel free to write your own answer about it; for example if someone has posted a code only answer and you want to deep dive explain it & make it easier to understand and explain it in good detail for the target audience, that's OK.. If it's an alternative way, like regex vs string vs linq, that's ok too

Comment: I agree with your statement, but I want you to know that these two answers were written like almost simultaneously. When I opened this question, there was no answer at this point. Just saw the other answer when I finished writing mine and reloaded this page.

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but i'd hazard a guess that it's because the answer merely repeats a 17 minutes earlier posted answer without adding anything. I fully believe it might have taken 17 minutes to write and research, and you might have used the mobile site where there is no huge orange banner saying "a new answer hs been posted" but we get an awful lot of this kind of noise on SO and the community is fairly understanding of how it arises and unwelcoming of it. I've seen very high rep users delete very good answers simply because they deemed them repeats; it's a risk one should be willing ..

Comment: ..to take if they want to play "fastest gun in the west". If you want to reduce the risk of finding yourself in that position, you can look for slightly older questions that are likely to have sat for a while because they're harder, weirder, more difficult to understand etc - of course, answers to those get fewer immediate upvotes because it seems like everyone is looking at the first page, get a quick answer in on an easy Q and get 5 upvotes for some puny one-liner vs maybe 1 upvote for doing good research into an older, harder Q- feels like a shitty deal but remember that you help the same..

Comment: ..number of people in either case, and really that's what the mission ought to be about. The voting and the unicorn points system is a bit screwed really; it has its merits in some long term senses but I wouldn't focus on it. Take a look at the behavioral differences between the sites top two repped users; one is an obvious educator who creates high quality content that millions of people learn from, the other just bashes out code only answer after code only answer, basically doing people's work for them and not really educating; the badge count difference between these two people is stark

Comment: Thanks for your long and insightful feedback. I will consider this the next time I answer a question. I guess I just leave this answer as it is right now, especially because of your comments. This may be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick a class which implements `IEnumerable<T>` - the most likely candidates are an array or a List

```
var search = new Search()
{
   Cardetail = new Cars[] { new Cars{ Id ="1"} }
};
```

or

```
var search = new Search()
{
   Cardetail = new List<Cars> { new Cars{ Id ="1"} }
};
```

As an aside, it is convention that the name of a class is singular so make that `Car` not `Cars`